# Get all rows that DBI::dbWriteTable has just written

Tags: r, database, postgresql, odbc

I want to use `dbWriteTable()` of R's `DBI` package to write data into a database. Usually, the respective tables are already present so I use the argument `append = TRUE`. How do I get which rows were added to the table by `dbWriteTable()`? Most of tables have certain columns with `UNIQUE` values so a `SELECT` will work (see below for a simple example). However, this is not true for all of them or only several columns together are `UNIQUE` making the `SELECT` more complicated. In addition, I would like to put the writing and querying into a function so I would prefer a consistent approach for all cases.

I mainly need this to get the `PRIMARY KEY`'s added by the database and to allow a user to quickly see what was added. If important, my database is PostgreSQL and I would like to use the `odbc` package for connection.

I have something like this in mind, however, I am looking for a more general solution:

```
library(DBI)

con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), dsn = "database")
dbWriteTable(con, 
             name = "site", value = data.frame(name = c("abcd", "efgh"), 
             append = TRUE))
dbGetQuery(conn,
           paste("SELECT * FROM site WHERE name in ('abcd', 'efgh');"))
```

Comment: You could retrieve all the PK values before inserting your rows, retrieve them again just after, and compute the set difference.

Comment: @Scarabee Thanks for the hint. This analysis of the PK values is done in R and not in the database, isn't it? (Sorry for the noobish question, I am very new to databases in general.)

Comment: Both options are possible. Or you could also create in your `site` table a new column containing the datetime of the insert, and another one containing the name of the user, and use these 2 columns to query the inserted rows.